# A way to add a callback to Geocoding JSON response on Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jsonp

So I have a URL like:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&sensor=false&address=1330+SW%203rd%20Ave,%20Portland,%20OR

But it returns *just* JSON. Im looking to do a JSONP call. I want to do this without server side code. Is there a way to add a var name to it or a function? Normally APIs have a `callback` param or something. Or, do any of you know any hacks? My code right now is:

```
createScriptTag:function(the_src,callback){
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],         
        newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.onload=callback;
    newScript.src = the_src;
    headID.appendChild(newScript);
  }

 //Then call it like:
 createScriptTag(
   'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&sensor=false&address=1330+SW%203rd%20Ave,%20Portland,%20OR',
   function(){ /* I can't do anything with the JSON :( */ }
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you're using the Geocoder API rather than the Maps API. According to the documentation the Geocoder API is not designed for real time use:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

> This service is generally designed for
>   geocoding static (known in advance)
>   addresses for placement of application
>   content on a map; this service is not
>   designed to respond in real time to
>   user input, for example. For dynamic
>   geocoding (for example, within a user
>   interface element), consult the
>   documentation for the JavaScript API
>   V2 Client Geocoder, the JavaScript API
>   V3 Client Geocoder, or the Maps API
>   for Flash Client Geocoder.

Perhaps you need to look at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding which is client side with built in callbacks. Although I believe the licence on that API requires the geocode result to be used in conjunction with a google map.